# When does file stream locking occur in glibc?

Tags: c, io, gnu, glibc

Reading the glibc documentation, I recently learned that calls to getc may have to wait to acquire a lock to read a file.  I wanted to verify that when using buffering a lock is only acquired when the actual file needs to be read to replenish the buffer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock invoked by `getc` provides application-level locking of the stdio FILE object, to allow thread-safe access to the same FILE object by multiple threads in the same application. As such, it *will* need to be acquired every time a character is read, not just when the buffer is replenished.

But, if you aren't accessing the FILE from multiple threads, you'll never have to wait for the lock. If the overhead of acquiring/releasing the lock is too much (measure this; don't just assume), you also have the option of manually locking/unlocking using `flockfile` and `funlockfile`, then using `getc_unlocked`.

Comment: There is no reason at all to use `flockfile` and `funlockfile` unless you have multiple threads trying to access the same `FILE` (which is almost surely a bug unless it's something like printing text output a whole line at a time).

Comment: @R Exactly right. If you know it's a single thread you can dispense with the lock/unlock when using `getc_unlocked`, although you almost certainly should just be using `getc` in the first place.

Comment: I think I see, because the buffer is shared by the (possibly) multiple threads?  Definitely this is at present a hypothetical question for me (for now).

Comment: @David, you are right it's best to use getc if possible, but if you do use getc_unlocked, you might as well use flockfile/funlockfile, that way you are not making any extra assumptions.  Also the validity of the code becomes apparent to the reader.

Comment: My comment that `flockfile` is not useful is actually probably wrong. If you're sure a `FILE` will only be used in one thread, it might be a good idea to permanently lock it with `flockfile`. This way, `FILE` operations will only have to increment/decrement a recursive lock count rather than performing memory synchronization instructions to obtain and release the actual lock. On some archs where atomic ops are expensive even without cache line contention, it could make a big difference.